# Smarty special character issue

Tags: php, utf-8, smarty

I used spanish language in my site. when iinserted the character like í,á,é,ó it will insert properly in db,but it cannot display in front-end, it display like this � in front-end

for example :

```
   Insert name : Test teachér in database it inserted correctly but in front it display as
Test teach�r.
```

i used  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`
also but no changes at all.

Comment: Did you saved document (file) as utf-8 too? Don´t you set another encoding in PHP before? Are database data sotred in utf-8, if you use database?

Comment: This is very broad question. You may get data from database without setting correct encoding, you may use some extra functions that modify output. You should look at phpmyadmin first if data is correct in database, show us how you get data from database and assign them to smarty and show smarty code how you display it

Comment: Marcin did you get my question what i am expecting for? i used general Collation: utf8_general_ci in database.

Comment: Yes, I get it, but you can have problems with multiple places. Without providing exact details we can only guess what could be wrong. For example you could use somewhere `substr` or `strtolower` function and it would also cause a problem. I don't say you don't use them. I simply don't know because lack of many details and code in your question

Comment: Can you please tell me what are the details you want,i send the details what you experted

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with smarty.

1. Check db charset where you store data and set it to UTF-8 General CI
2. Check charset of db connection `SET NAMES utf8`
3. Check the output of script if it's in UTF you can do it with meta charset, or in headers content-type.

`Content-type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"`

or

`<meta charset="utf-8">` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

After these operations you should have proper output.

You can also optionally check if functions that work on strings supports UTF-8.

Comment: i used <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> in header and while inserting i used mysql_set_charset('utf8');